# MySQL: Select newest record from table for every user I talked to

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

`users` schema:

[image]

`private_messages` schema:

[image]

`time_sent` is a datetime. All other fields are varchars and ints.

`sender_id` and `receiver_id` both refer to `id` in `users`.

**What I want:**

Given a `users` `id`, say 1, select the last sent message for every other user (whether the given user sent it or the other user sent it).  It should return all the columns of the `private_messages` table along with the other user's `username`, and ordered by the `time_sent`.

The functionality I'm trying to achieve is that of when you open up all of your text messages, and you can see a preview of the last message sent between you and everyone else. This query is killing me because of the fact that the given users id can appear in either the `sender_id` or the `receiver_id`. Please help me out with writing the query.

Here is exported sql code to create the tables and their contents (just in case you want something to test with):

[users](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uYJkdrQgvW8meNHxOI_QK81D8oTApuCC841iM2Lxdrs/edit?usp=sharing)

[private_messages](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OVX-tCZExO5pEVrkil0_kKHslmIpLWbtIu2Jc8KPMNU/edit?usp=sharing)

[private_messages 2](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fRUK7qqXdgJKhHgbT0U1tEyjY5_D7h3yyLwZ6-tM1Bo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Perhaps something like this: `SELECT pm.*, u.username FROM privatemessages pm INNER JOIN users u ON (u.id = pm.sender_id OR u.id = pm.receiver_id) && (pm.sender_id = $supplied_id OR pm.receiver_id = $supplied_id) ORDER BY pm.sender_id, pm.receiver_id, pm.time_sent DESC`

Comment: @Cyclone It's a bit off, but I realized it's probably my fault for not including the code to create the tables along with their contents.  I attached the code.

Comment: You should edit your question and add what you've tried so far, some example data to the tables and also it would be nice if you could add an example of your desired output.

Comment: @Cyclone See the 2 attachments.  You should be able to copy and paste those into phpMyAdmin  (I'm assuming that's what you're using since you used a php variable.)

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
      SELECT U.username,
             U2.username,
             IF(PM.sender_id = U.id, 'Sent', 'Received') AS `action`,
             PM.message, 
             PM.time_sent             
        FROM users U
  INNER JOIN private_messages PM ON (PM.sender_id = U.id OR PM.receiver_id = U.id)
  INNER JOIN users U2 ON (U2.id = IF(PM.sender_id = U.id, PM.receiver_id, PM.sender_id))  
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                  FROM private_messages NXT_PM
                 WHERE NXT_PM.time_sent > PM.time_sent
                   AND (
                         ( NXT_PM.sender_id = PM.sender_id  AND NXT_PM.receiver_id = PM.receiver_id )
                       OR 
                         (  NXT_PM.receiver_id = PM.sender_id  AND NXT_PM.sender_id = PM.receiver_id )
                       )
             )       
         AND U.username = 'Kacy'
    ORDER BY time_sent DESC
```

This returns:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| username | username | action   | message  | time_sent           |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| Kacy     | liz      | Sent     | hi again | 2015-03-08 10:47:26 |
| Kacy     | Jamie    | Sent     | hi       | 2015-03-07 23:01:18 |
| Kacy     | tracy    | Received | hi       | 2015-03-06 12:04:34 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: This is great.  I just added U.id and U2.id to the selection.  (I need the ids because I use them in a lot of hashmaps and sparsearrays on the client side and sometimes use it to query a few other things later.)  Thank you very much.

Comment: I added a few more messages, and the query no longer completely works.
  For some reason it leaves out the Sent message to liz.

Comment: It breaks when Kacy receives a  message from Jamie rather then sends one.

Comment: I fixed it.  I think you knew exactly what you were doing, but you made a small blooper when actually typing it (which I don't blame you since it's a pretty big query).  Where you had `NXT_PM.receiver_id = PM.sender_id` on the right side of the last `AND` statement , it should be `NXT_PM.sender_id = PM.receiver_id`. I submitted an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below technique for getting max per group

```
select 
u1.username as sender, 
u2.username as receiver, 
m.message,
m.time_sent 
from private_messages m 
inner join users u1 on u1.id = m.sender_id 
inner join users u2 on u2.id = m.receiver_id 
left join private_messages m1 on m1.sender_id = m.sender_id 
and m1.receiver_id = m.receiver_id 
and m1.time_sent > m.time_sent 
where m.sender_id = 1 
and m1.id is null ;
```

You can also use

```
and m1.id > m.id
```

instead of

```
and m1.time_sent > m.time_sent
```

if `id` is auto-incremented in `private_messages` table

If you need to see data as both sender and receiver for a given user the condition would be as

```
 where ( m.sender_id = 1 or m.receiver_id = 1 ) and m1.id is null
```

instead of

```
where m.sender_id = 1 
and m1.id is null ;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Wow that was seriously amazing.  It is very close.  The only problem is that the sender's username is always the one belonging to the given id.  I attached the code to my question to create the tables and their contents in case you want to test it yourself.

Comment: Oh I see, in your query you assume that the given user is always the sender of the last message.  But the other user could have sent the last message to me as well.

Comment: The condition would be as `where ( m.sender_id = 1 or m.receiver_id = 1 ) and m1.id is null`

Comment: I's close, but if there is a conversation between A and B, and A sent the last message to B, the query should not return the last message B sent to A.

Comment: Gave it an upvote.  Even though it doesn't fit my exact needs, it could definitely be useful to someone else who finds themselves in this scenario.